# Passing a variable to Pug/Jade's Tag Interpolation feature

Tags: pug

Quote of the official Pug page regarding Tag Interpolation:

> Interpolation works not only on JavaScript values, but on Pug as well. You could accomplish the same thing by writing an HTML tag inline with your Pug…but then, what’s the point of writing the Pug? Wrap an inline Pug tag declaration in **#[ and ]**, and it’ll be evaluated and buffered into the content of its containing tag.

In simple words, what I take from here is that I can evaluate Pug language from whatever I put inside a `#[]`.

And that's really the behavior. Example:

**(something.pug):**

```
h5 My name is #[-console.log('hi from serverside')] //outputs hi from serverside
```

However, I want to be able to pass a variable to the interpolation part, like this:

**(not working):**

```
-var john = -console.log('hi from serverside') //will render now
-console.log(typeof john) // number o.O
h5 My name is #[john] //but now nothing
```

I guess maybe I need to do some type conversion? `typeof x` shows the variable is a number, but `Number(john)` just caused the variable to return `NaN`.

**How can I pass a variable to `#[x]` that will actually run?**

Comment: The dash (`-`) that lets you write javascript in pug can only be used at the beginning of a line, not within a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for Pug's tag interpolation feature requires a tag to be defined.

**Example 1**

```
h5 My name is #[span]
```

is the same as

```
h5 My name is
    span
```

Both of which compile to

```
<h5> My name is
    <span></span>
</h5>
```

**Example 2**

In the same sense, this:

```
h5 My name is #[myName]
```

is the same as

```
h5 My name is
    myName
```

Both of which compile to

```
<h5> My name is
    <myName></myName>
</h5>
```

regardless of if `myName` is a previously defined javascript variable.

**Example 3**

The proper use of inline tag interpolation looks like this:

```
h4 Hello, my name is #[span John Wick]
```

Which compiles to:

```
<h4>Hello, my name is <span>John Wick</span></h4>
```

Its purpose is to allow more semantic placement of inline tags within Pug.

**Example 4**

If you want to output a variable as a string, use regular [string interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-escaped):

```
- var name = 'John'

h4 Hello my name is ${name}
```

Compiles to:

```
<h4>Hello my name is John</h4>
```

**Example 5**

If you want to use inline tag interpolation with regular string interpolation of variables you can do that too:

```
- var name = 'John Wick'

h4 Hello, my name is #[span ${name}]
```

But you need to specify what tag is being used (`span` in this case)

**Example 6**

If you need to, you can also make that tag name dynamic:

```
- var myTag = 'em'
- var myName = 'John Wick'

h4 Hello, my name is #[${myTag} ${myName}]
```

compiles to:

```
<h4>Hello, my name is <em>John Wick</em></h4>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I too was wondering how to achieve this.

Given the input:

```js
const name = 'John Wick';
```

How can the following output be produced?

```html
<h4>Hello, my name is <em>John Wick</em></h4>
```

I was looking at Example 5 in the accepted answer which uses `${}` as the string interpolation, but this didn't seem to work with the latest pug at the time of writing (2.0.4). Maybe that example is for jade aka pug v1?

The syntax that worked for me was to use `#{}` as follows:

```
- const name = 'John Wick';
h4 Hello, my name is #[em #{name}]
```